# My lemon tree is having major problems

Tags: plant-health, citrus, lemons

I live in Southern California and the bark on my tree is splitting, there are limbs also splitting off and the fruit is green instead of yellow. This tree is about fifty years old and I want to save it. Any suggestions.

Comment: See this URL on some causes of bark splitting: https://www.sandyoaks.com/BarkSplittingMSU.pdf I don't know about your situation, but when it comes to bark, stems and such, I suspect NPK ratio imbalances and/or a calcium imbalance, along with severe weather.

Comment: "The fruit is green" Are they green only on the bottom and is the fruit distorted in any manner? Can you describe the coloring of the leaves?

Comment: They are green all over with the exception of a couple of yellow lemons.  The fruit look normal except that they are green instead of yellow.  The leaves on my tree are green.  I took some pictures with my iPad but they were too large and the site would not me upload any of them.

Comment: This might be a nutrient deficient, but to rule out the worse case scenario: Do the leaves have a mottled discoloration or is the green uniform? Do you observe any stunted growth?

Comment: No the green is uniformed and I don't see any stunted growth.  I did go to a nursery yesterday and they looked at my pictures. They said that my tree appears to be over 50 years old and suggested that I cut off the - I think they called them suckers, and put some nutrients into the soil to see if that helps.  They also said that trees have life spans but that they think that I should get another few years out of it.